# pandas divide df n x m by series length g by index

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of n x m and a pandas series of length g. How can I divide the dataframe by series based on the index?

So far, I've been merging the series with the dataframe and the simply dividing one cell by the other.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a representative example as it really depends, for example if the length doesn't match then it will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC if length of `Series` is same as length of `df` use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
print (s)
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int6

print (df.div(s, axis=0))
     A    B    C         D    E    F
0  1.0  4.0  7.0  1.000000  5.0  7.0
1  1.0  2.5  4.0  1.500000  1.5  2.0
2  1.0  2.0  3.0  1.666667  2.0  1.0
```

If lengths are different, you get `NaN`:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2])
print (s)
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64

print (df.div(s, axis=0))
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0  1.0  4.0  7.0  1.0  5.0  7.0
1  1.0  2.5  4.0  1.5  1.5  2.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: if my question was not clear, I have different lengths, but the indexes are the same. Thus I'd like to divide by indexes

Comment: So my solution doesnt work for you? If not, can you add desired output with my samples?